# Inequality between probability of intersection and product of probabilities

Tags: probability, inequality

Is it true that for any events $A, B \subseteq S$, $S$ being the sample space, the probabilities of $A$, $B$, and their intersection satisfy
$$
P(A \cap B) \geq P(A) P(B)
$$
I tried to prove it, but to no avail. I tried to disprove it with examples, but could only find example that satisfied it. Of course, the equality holds if $A$ and $B$ are independent, but what about the general case?

Comment: **Hint:** What happens if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive nontrivial events?

Comment: if $A$ and $B$ are disjoint the inequality is violated.

Comment: What if the events are mutually exclusive?

Comment: As an aside, there are times when $P(A\cap B)> P(A)P(B)$ and there are other times where $P(A\cap B)<P(A)P(B)$, so we can not do much to correct the problem statement to make it true.

Comment: What happens if $A\cap B=\oslash$?

Answer (score 1):

As many commented, if $A \cap B = \varnothing$, but $P(A) \neq 0 \neq P(B)$, then $P(A \cap B) = 0 < P(A) P(B)$ and the inequality is violated.

Thank you all!